# How to create large array of integers to test LongCount?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I want to allocate a large array of integers to test the LongCount operator. The LongCount operator is used when, [quote](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb353539(v=vs.100).aspx):

> you expect the result to be greater than MaxValue.

So to prepare for my test, I want to allocate an array of integers which is just a little larger than `Int32.MaxValue`:

```
Int64[] arr = new Int64[Int32.MaxValue + 10UL];
```

But this throws an `OverflowException`.

What I want to do is something like this:

```
Int64[] arr = new Int64[Int32.MaxValue + 10UL];

var res = arr.LongCount();
```

And then expect `res` to be `2147483657` (which is `Int32.MaxValue + 10`).

How can I do this?

Comment: are you testing .NET framework? Install more RAM, use `byte` instead of  `Int64`

Comment: What happens when you change [Int32.MaxValue + 10UL] to simply [2147483657]?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not constructive

Comment: @SteveFerg: This gives an OverflowException as well.

Comment: @dotctor's answer is right, but even if you were able to do this, your array would be using over 17 GB of memory.

Comment: and that's still invalid since CLR Objects can not become larger than 2GB. @Sam

Comment: I still don't get what is the purpose of testing LongCount?? What exactly do you want to test?

Comment: @dotctor: I'm just comparing Count and LongCount, and want to see for myself how I can test LongCount. Unfortunately testing LongCount is not easy.

Comment: you can compare them with an array with length `10` one of them return an `int`, the other one return a `long`

Comment: The CLR is saving you from yourself ;-) by not allocating more than you may have physical memory + swap allocation memory.

Comment: Why in world do you need to create an array of Int64 (let alone bit)  to test LongCount when an array is limited Int32 and LongCount is property of IEnumerable?  Why are you even testing LongCount?  -1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write your own list implementation to store several arrays and link them together (or most likely there's already a better one some where..). Map your huge `ulong` int two `Int32` indexes to get there, implement the `IEnumerable` interface on it, and test away.

```
ulong listSize = Int32.MaxValue + 10UL;
BigList<bool> myList = new BigList<bool>(listSize);
Debug.Assert(myList.LongCount() == (long)listSize);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Example implementation..

```
public class BigList<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private List<T[]> _storage = new List<T[]>();

    private const int _maxStorageArraySize = 1000;

    public ulong Capacity { get; private set; }

    public BigList(ulong capacity) 
    {
        _storage = new List<T[]>();

        Capacity = capacity;

        int arraysRequired = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)capacity / (double)_maxStorageArraySize);
        int lastArraySize = (int)(capacity % (ulong)_maxStorageArraySize);

        for (int i = 0; i < arraysRequired; i++)
            _storage.Add(new T[(i + 1) < arraysRequired ? _maxStorageArraySize : lastArraySize]);
    }

    public T this[ulong idx]
    {
        get
        {
            int arrayIdx = (int)(idx / (ulong)_maxStorageArraySize);
            int arrayOff = (int)(idx % (ulong)_maxStorageArraySize);
            return _storage[arrayIdx][arrayOff];
        }
        set
        {
            int arrayIdx = (int)(idx / (ulong)_maxStorageArraySize);
            int arrayOff = (int)(idx % (ulong)_maxStorageArraySize);

            _storage[arrayIdx][arrayOff] = value;
        }
    }

    public class BigListEnumerator : IEnumerator<T>
    {
        private BigList<T> _bigList;
        private ulong _idx;

        public BigListEnumerator(BigList<T> bigList)
        {
            _bigList = bigList;
        }
        public T Current
        {
            get { return _bigList[_idx]; }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _bigList = null;
        }

        object System.Collections.IEnumerator.Current
        {
            get { return Current; }
        }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            return _idx++ < _bigList.Capacity;
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            _idx = 0;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new BigListEnumerator(this);
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new BigListEnumerator(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need array to test LongCount?  It is property of IEnumerable?

Comment: You don't *need* to. If you want to see for yourself and believe for yourself something works, in whatever way you want to, why not.

Comment: Side note - there is really no need for chunked array implementation for this question. Basic counter with `yield return 1;` should be all that is needed to demonstrate [Enumerable.LongCount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548914(v=vs.100).aspx)....

Comment: Why do you need for there to be actual arrays underneath the enumerator? A `for` loop with a `long` index `yield return`ing zeroes will do just fine. Definitely an overkill :)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need an array and you shouldn't use one. It is not necessary to dedicate 2GB of memory to this test (with a `byte[]`). This is all it takes:

```
var items = Enumerable.Range(0, int.MaxValue).Concat(Enumerable.Range(0, 10));
```

Use that as the source. Or write your own `RangeLong` method that consists of a for loop ranging over a long variable. That will be faster because the items pass through less iterators. At this amount of items performance becomes a concern.

Answer (score 2):

the problem is that maximum size that an array can hold is `System.Int32.MaxValue` and when you want to create an array that has more elements than `System.Int32.MaxValue` it will thrown an `OverflowException`